# how to make text entered in text area correspond to specific radio button?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, textarea, entity-relationship

I have built a form with radio buttons.

What I want to do now is this: next to each group of radio buttons, add a text area. The user should be able to make a selection either by selecting the radio button, or by entering the corresponding value in the text area.

I'd also like to make the value of the selected radio button appear in the text area.

Is there a way to link the two of them?

My markup is:

```
<label>Nationality:</label> <br>
<input type="radio" name="nationality" value="null">
<input type="radio" name="nationality" value="greek">Greece
<input type="radio" name="nationality" value="italian">Italy
<input type="radio" name="nationality" value="german">Germany
<input type="radio" name="nationality" value="russian">Russia
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use javascript to make the value of the radio appear in your textarea

For your question about the choice, not sure if i understood, but it's on php side i think

If the user choose radio
No need for textarea

If the user choose textarea
no need for radio

But i think you should also link each radio item with his textarea, so in php, you know which radio corresponds to which textarea,and thus make a test to be sure the visitor entered the correct textarea